# Laravel 9 Class "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Rules\Password" not found

Tags: laravel-9, laravel-breeze

I created a basic laravel 9 app. I added new fields to the RegisteredUserController

example:
surname
address
company_name

I keep getting error

```
Class "App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Rules\Password" not found
```

and laravel 9 refers me to the default validation for password

```
'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
```

I never changed any of the original codes but simple added new fields to my blade and also my controller

My updated RegisteredUserController code

```
  $request->validate([
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
    ]);
    $profilepic = $request->file('profile_pic');

    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'surname' => $request->surname,
        'company' => $request->company,
        'profile_pic' => $profilepic,
        'department' => $request->department,
        'message' => $request->message,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    ]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing an import for Rules\Password, those should come from the Illuminate package, add the following:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;
```